# Backup site can it be restore on another sps 2013 server

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I have backed a site running in production (sps2013) can I restore it to my sps2013 in dev environment.

Any prechecks or issues performing the restore?

Answer (score 4):

The only thing you would need to do before restoring is validate that the patch levels of both farms match as Restore-SPSite will not allow you to restore a Site Collection backup to a farm with a different patch level.

If you're taking a Content Databases for restoration into the dev environment, the dev environment just cannot have a lower patch level than the production environment, but it may be higher. Content Databases are automatically upgraded when you use `Mount-SPContentDatabase`.

Comment: but definitely you can overcome these limitations to some extent by site export options.